# JavaScript static function in callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, asynchronous, callback

Hi I've been trying to clarify this but there's something I'm still confused about. I know that you can't return values from asynchronous functions so I've referenced this answer's top answer [Returning value from asynchronous JavaScript method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211023/returning-value-from-asynchronous-javascript-method)

What I'm trying to do is use the flickrAPI to get the biggest size image. The flickrAPI allows one to search images, so I use this to get the photo_id, then I use this photo_id to procses another request to the API's getSize method to get the URL for the biggest size photo.

The code looks a little messy as it is, because I have a method called flickrRequest which sends an XMLHttp request and gets back a JSON string. I know that I can achieve what I want by writing the functions as follows:

```
function flickRQforimage() {
    ...got ID
    function flickrRQforSize() {
        ...got maxsizeURL
        create image based on maxsizeURL here
    }
}
```

but I was wondering if it was possible to do something like this

```
function flickRQforimage() {
    ...got ID
    function flickrRQforSize() {
        ...got maxsizeURL

    }
    create image based on maxsizeURL here
}
or even create image based on maxsizeURL here
```

In general my question is whether it is possible to have a callback function that references another statically defined function (I think?). The specifics of the my function is that it takes a callback and the ID and URL processing happens in those callbacks:

```
flickrRQ(options, cb)
```

I am wondering whether/what would happen if that unnamed function is instead something else, say flickrRQ(options, processPhoto(data)), and then I define the function in a separate method. This just makes sense for me because I want to keep functionality for the URL processing separate in an attempt to make my code cleaner and more readable.

I tried the following below and it didn't work. Nothing prints. I even have a console.log in the processPhoto method. In fact anything inside of the flickrRQforSize method seems to not evaluate

```
flickrRQforSize(options, function(data) {
    processPhoto(data)
}
```

even though in the flickrRQforSize definition, a callback function is taken as an argument. I'm suspecting there must be something about functions/async calls that I don't understand.

I hope this is clear -- if not, I can post my actual code.

Here's my code:

```
var flickrRequest = function(options, xhrRQ, cb) {
    var url, xhr, item, first;
    url = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/";
    first = true;

    for (item in options) {
        if (options.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
            url += (first ? "?" : "&") + item + "=" + options[item];    
            //parses to search equest; 
            first = false;
        }
    }
    //XMLHttpRQ to flickr
    if(xhrRQ == 1 ) { 
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function() { cb(this.response); };
        xhr.open('get', url, true);
        xhr.send();
    };
}

var processPhotoSize = function(photoJSON) {
    var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(data); 
    var last = parsedJSON.sizes.size.length;
    console.log(parsedJSON.sizes.size[last-1].source);
    return parsedJSON.sizes.size[last-1].source;
}
...
flickrRequest(options, 1, function(data) {
    ...
    flickrRequest(sizesOptions, 0, function(data) {
            parsedJSON = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(parsedJSON); 
            processPhotoSize(data); 
        });         
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible, and quite common. Just make sure to hardcode the callback only when it is an essential part of the function, to still maintain separation of concerns.

Comment: Your `flickrRQforSize` looks fine (except for the missing closing `)`), so if it doesn't work you should show us the rest of your code in a less pseudecode-like format.

Comment: posted relevant code: i just noticed that i'm doing xhr.onload = function() { cb(this.response); }; which might have something to do with it? also right now you see a "return" in the processPhotoSize function and it shouldn't be there, but even so the console.log in that function doesn't trigger

Comment: Uh, what is this `xhrRQ` parameter and what does it mean when it's set to `0`? In your second `flickrRequest` call, `cb` will never be called back.

Comment: The `return` in `processPhotoSize` is totally fine, as it is a synchronous function. Only it's caller needs to do something with the result, and consume it as a return value in this case.

Comment: @Bergi the xhrRQ param I used because I do the URL creation in there and use that URL somewhere else without actually sending an http request. so I do flickrRequest(options, 0) when I just want the URL. I should definitely separate those methods

Comment: @Bergi `xhrRQ` appear to be `1` at `flickrRequest(options, 1, function(data) {` ?

Comment: @Bergi oh I see, that was really silly of me. but in general this would work?

Comment: Wait actually I'm so wrong. I should delete this question. It should be 1 both times because the cb should only be called if JSON is returned, and JSON is returned and parsed in this method. Not sure why I got stuck.

Comment: @guest271314. Not in `flickrRequest(sizesOptions, 0, function(data) {`

Comment: @frei: Yes, you should absolutely separate those methods.